# Unexpected behavior, scope block and sync/async confusion

Tags: angular, typescript, asynchronous, scope

**Update:** I've been playing some with the code and discovered that what I originally wrote was not entirely correct so I edited the question accordingly. Now it's even simpler but I still cannot figure out what causes the strange behavior.

---

I'm relatively new to TypeScript and Angular and experiencing some very strange operation I don't understand. I have the following snippet from a component:

```
...
private formSchema: FormlyFieldConfig = [];

constructor(private http: Http) {
  this.http.get('assets/form_sample.json').subscribe(res => {
    let formSchema = res.json().formSchema;
    for (let row of formSchema.fieldGroup) {
      console.log(row);
    }
    //this.formSchema = new Array(formSchema);
  });
}
...
```

It reads in some JSON data, traverses an array in it and outputs its elements onto the console. The program works as expected. But now comes the funny part. Let's just slightly modify the code:

```
...
private formSchema: FormlyFieldConfig = [];

constructor(private http: Http) {
  this.http.get('assets/form_sample.json').subscribe(res => {
    let formSchema = res.json().formSchema;
    for (let row of formSchema.fieldGroup) {
      console.log(row);
    }
    this.formSchema = new Array(formSchema);
  });
}
...
```

All I did was uncomment a line. I'd expect the program to deliver the same results but instead it strangely misbehaves: The output on the console changes: Previously it only contained data from the JSON file as expected, but now it has a bunch of other things in it: data and names of variables and functions implemented in the FormlyFieldConfig interface. And I just don't get it how this can happen.

It seems that the line I uncommented is responsible for *console.log(row)* delivering different data. What's happening here? How can this line act on another one executed in the past?

Comment: Could you add a plnkr? I don't see any wrong with the snippets..

Comment: The mystery is solved. Both snippets do exactly the same. It was the browser (Firefox) that misled me: If I do `console.log(JSON.stringify(row))`, the outputs are the same in both cases. But without stringify, one sees `Object { className: "row", fieldGroup: Array[3] }` in the console, and then clicking `Array` opens its content in an additional side pane at the right side of the console, which already differs for some reason depending on whether the line `this.formSchema = new Array(formSchema)` is in the code. So there's no problem at all, still it'd be nice to know why the browser does so.